# Erro com um alerta Jquery e html

Tags: jquery, html

estou fazendo um alerta com jquery.... 
a função dele é mostrar ao usuario o erro e dependendo da acao levar a uma seguinte pagina... bom ja testei e o erro está no jquery pois quando eu coloco o alerta em html puro ele aparece perfeitamente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse exemplo acima está com html... o jeito que devia aparecer.

Vamos ao codigo

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var  site = {

fechar: function(parametro){
    $('#alerta-preto').fadeOut(2000);
    $('#alerta-base').fadeOut(2000)
    location.href="http://www.site.com.br/"+parametro+"";
    }

alerta: function(conteudo,diretorio){
html = '';
html += '<div id="alerta-preto"></div>';
html += '<div id="alerta-base">';
html += '<div id="alerta-topo">Alerta <div id="alerta-fechar" onclick="site.fechar("'+diretorio+'")"></div></div>';
html += '<div  id="alerta-branco">';
html += '<div class="titulo"><b>Ops,</b> Alerta</div>';
html += ''+conteudo+'';
html += '</div>';
html += '</div>';   
$('#alerta-fly').append(html);
}
}
});
```

fica +- assim para chamar

```
//apenas para mostrar
site.alerta('Dados incorretos.','nao');
//para direcionar
site.alerta('Logado com sucesso.','inicio');
```

o problema é q não funciona....
chequei esse codigo varia vezes e está bem ao meu ver...

Comment: Leandro há alguma mensagem de erro para mostrar? Coloque para que possamos ajudar você.

Comment: esse alerta é uma acao de erro do tipo : o usuario errou a senha ... ai aparece aquela box -- Dados incorretos...

Comment: Ok vc executa e não aparece correto?

Comment: dá algum erro no console?

Comment: Já encontrei alguns erros, estou criando uma resposta

Comment: blz.. n posso checar no console por que o servidor deu pal POR PURA CONHECIDENCIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente suas funções dentro da variável site, poderão ser executados em qualquer contexto do site. Então você não pode restringir ela dentro do **$(document).ready**

> Abaixo segue o código para teste
>
> **Nota:** Comentei o método para direcionar, para efetuar o teste descomente o mesmo.

```
var site = {
    fechar: function(parametro){
        $('#alerta-preto').fadeOut(2000, function (){
                $('#alerta-base').fadeOut(2000, function (){
                    if(parametro != undefined) {
                        location.href="http://www.site.com.br/"+parametro+"";
                    }
                });  
        });
    },
    alerta: function(conteudo,diretorio){
        var html = '<div id="alerta-preto"></div>';
        html += '<div id="alerta-base">';
        html += '<div id="alerta-topo">Alerta <div id="alerta-fechar" onclick="site.fechar("'+diretorio+'")"></div></div>';
        html += '<div  id="alerta-branco">';
        html += '<div class="titulo"><b>Ops,</b> Alerta</div>';
        html += conteudo;
        html += '</div>';
        html += '</div>';   
        $('#alerta-fly').html( html );
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //apenas para mostrar
    site.alerta('Dados incorretos.');
    //para direcionar
    // site.alerta('Logado com sucesso.','inicio');
});
```

Comment: perfeito man obrigado... vc n sabe o quanto me ajudou..
deu pra perceber q eu n manjo mt de jquery mais nada q o tempo n arrume... Vlw continua assim!

Comment: Não me lembro se é proibido indicar livros pagos aqui na comunidade, mas segue o link de um ótimo livro. Ele é bastante prático e ajuda muito, estude Java Script também. http://www.novatec.com.br/livros/jquery3ed/